# как переписать условный оператор в тернарный оператор в js

Tags: javascript

Код выглядит вот так:

```
let a = 100,
    b = 99;

let max;

if (a > b) {
    max = a;
} else {
    max = b;
}
```

Comment: `let max = (a > b) ? a : b;`???

Comment: EOF неверно: вот ошибка: "<a class='gotoLine' href='#42:11'>42:11</a> Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined"

Comment: А понял как исправит ща пару сек.

Comment: EOF вот так правильно:

Comment: let a = 100
let b = 99
let max = (a > b) ? a : b;
console.log(max)

Comment: Это прям совсем готовое решение.

Comment: Был вопрос: "как переписать условный оператор в тернарный оператор в js"? Ни про какие выводы и инициализации речь не шла.

Comment: и чем это решение отличается от EOF?

Comment: У EOF не обозначено значение переменных как в исходном коде

Comment: А про вывод мой косяк

Answer (score 2):

Тернарный оператор имеет вид

```
условие ? выражение1 : выражение2
```

Если `условие` истинно, то результатом всего выражения будет `выражение1`, иначе `выражение2`.
Вот Ваш же код, но с использованием тернарного оператора:

```
let a = 100;
let b = 99;

let max = (a > b) ? a : b;
```